# SCRIPT tag contents being escaped in IFRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe, redactor

I have an IFRAME for an HTML editor (redactor). When retrieving the `innerHTML` of that IFRAME (`iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML`), it is escaping every dollar sign inside of a SCRIPT tag. It also does other things, like replace SPAN tags with INLINE.

For example, I load this string into the IFRAME:

```
<html><head><script>$</script><body><span>$</span></body></html>
```

And then I retrieve it like so:

```
console.log(iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML);
//prints
//<html><head><script>&#36;</script><body><inline>$</inline></body></html>
```

Is there any way to prevent this, especially the SCRIPT tag escaping?

Comment: Are you trying to run javascript code from a server on a separate domain outside its sandbox? I hope you know what you're doing and/or trust that domain.

Comment: no, this is an iframe that i inject the content into. it is the html wysiwyg editor, redactor. there are no cross domain considerations.